# Update a string attribute in a Heroku production database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku

Trying to change one of the string descriptions in my production Heroku database but don't know how to do it.

After running `heroku run rails console`

and

`Location.where(id: 2)`

I have this:

`#<Location id: 2, name: "Camera 2", lat: -118.238275051117, long: 34.0491659368589, created_at: "2014-05-23 22:02:57", updated_at: "2014-05-23 22:02:57", description: "Convention Center">`

I am trying to update "description:" string from "Convention Center" to "Hollywood" and also the lat: and long: float attributes.

Is there a way to do in the Heroku console without having to erase and re-seed the entire thing?

I was thinking something like `Location.update(2) { location.update_attribute :description, "Hollywood" }`

and

`Location.update(2) { location.update_attribute :lat, -117.1335235 }`

but these aren't correct. I'm hoping it's a simple line command.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Location.find(2).update_attributes(description: "Hollywood", lat: 2393, long: 384)
```

Where `lat` and `long` are your integers/floats.

Comment: Beautiful, love the single entry method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After logging into heroku console, you can try this to update required attributes without reseeding entire object.

```
location = Location.find(2)
location.update_attribute(:description, "description text")
location.update_attribute(:lat,1.4535643)
```

The main difference between update_attribute and update_attributes is that update_attribute will not reseed object and its timestamps will not get updated.